# Tenses when talking about recorded video

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

When talking about a recorded video, what grammar tense should I use?

For example when taking about [this BABYMETAL interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbODbQMm5Wc) to someone:

> Me: Has anyone noticed how Yui **talks** about American?

Should it be **talked** or **talks**? It happened in the past but in the video she will always talk like that when people watching.

> Me: Yui **seems** to be timid, **it's** because the topic **is** more serious and **doesn't** fit laughing.

Same question as above.

Answer (score 3):

In conversations, storytelling and discussions when we see something happening just now, at the moment of speaking we can use the **Present Simple** or the **Present Continuous**, and the **Past Simple**.

Both your examples are correct.

Here are more examples:

- There's a video about a guy who's doing tricks on his motorcycle. You say, *"Look how fast he's **going**"* or *"Look how high he **jumped**"* or *"Look how he **does** it"*